# Verify multiple method calls with argument captor with different byte array arguments returns same value in all instances of getAllValues()

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

I am capturing the arguments of the following function

```
class Processor
{
    public void process(byte[] bs, int length)
    {
        // Make a local copy
        System.arraycopy(bs, 0, mRcvBuffer, 0, length);
        //do something
    }
}
```

using argument captor:

```
    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<byte[]> dataToProcess;
    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor <Integer>len;
```

the above method is called 3 times with different arguments from the tested function.
In the test case I verify that the it is called 3 times and capture the arguments

```
@Before
public void setup
{
    //set connection mock
    //set processor mock
}
@Test
public void test()
{
   testInstance.testFunction();
   verify(proessor,times(3)).process(dataToProcess.capture(), len.capture());
   List<byte[]> consumerData = dataToProcess.getAllValues();
   List<Integer> dataLengths= len.getAllValues();

   assertThat( expectedlen1, is(dataLengths.get(0)));
   assertThat( expectedlen2, is(dataLengths.get(1)));
   assertThat( expectedlen3, is(dataLengths.get(2)));

   Assert.assertArrayEquals( expectedData1, consumerData.get(0));
   Assert.assertArrayEquals( expectedData2, consumerData.get(1));
   Assert.assertArrayEquals( expectedData3, consumerData.get(2));


}

TestClass
{
    testFunction()
    {
          //fetch data from connection
          //do something
          processor.process(readData,length)
    }
}
```

The following assertions on consumed data fail but the assertions on length pass.
The problem: 
All entries of consumerData contain the third data set.
I verified with debugging that correct data was passed as arguments during the call.

Runner used:
`@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

Is there another approach to test the same scenario.